# How to fix asterisk 1.8.18+ compile error?

Tags: asterisk

I'm compile Asterisk 1.8.32.3(error persist from 1.8.18), and at the end i'm getting this error:

```
root@ubuntu:/usr/src/asterisk-1.8.32.3# make
CC="cc" CXX="" LD="" AR="" RANLIB="" CFLAGS="" make -C menuselect CONFIGURE_SILENT="--silent" makeopts
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/asterisk-1.8.32.3/menuselect'
make[1]: 'makeopts' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/asterisk-1.8.32.3/menuselect'
   [CC] tcptls.c -> tcptls.o
*tcptls.c: In function ‘tcptls_stream_close’:
tcptls.c:401:20: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
    if (!stream->ssl->server) {*
                    ^
tcptls.c:403:5: warning: ‘ERR_remove_state’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/openssl/err.h:261) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     ERR_remove_state(0);
     ^
tcptls.c: In function ‘__ssl_setup’:
tcptls.c:768:4: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘SSLv2_client_method’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    cfg->ssl_ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv2_client_method());
    ^
tcptls.c:768:4: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘SSL_CTX_new’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/src/asterisk-1.8.32.3/include/asterisk/tcptls.h:59:0,
                 from tcptls.c:44:
/usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:1503:17: note: expected ‘const struct SSL_METHOD *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 __owur SSL_CTX *SSL_CTX_new(const SSL_METHOD *meth);
                 ^
tcptls.c:773:4: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘SSLv3_client_method’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    cfg->ssl_ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv3_client_method());
    ^
tcptls.c:773:4: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘SSL_CTX_new’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/src/asterisk-1.8.32.3/include/asterisk/tcptls.h:59:0,
                 from tcptls.c:44:
/usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:1503:17: note: expected ‘const struct SSL_METHOD *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 __owur SSL_CTX *SSL_CTX_new(const SSL_METHOD *meth);
                 ^
tcptls.c:775:4: warning: ‘TLSv1_client_method’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:1879) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    cfg->ssl_ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_client_method());
    ^
/usr/src/asterisk-1.8.32.3/Makefile.rules:109: recipe for target 'tcptls.o' failed
make[1]: *** [tcptls.o] Error 1
Makefile:351: recipe for target 'main' failed
make: *** [main] Error 2
```

Most important are lines:

```
tcptls.c: In function ‘tcptls_stream_close’:
tcptls.c:401:20: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
    if (!stream->ssl->server) {
                    ^
```

I'm using dahdi 2.11.2 and g++/gcc 4.8;
Compile on Ubuntu 16.04

**Do someone know how to fix this issue ?**

P.S. I need to compile only asterisk 1.8.18+ and only on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution by myself:

To compile and install asterisk, it's needed gcc/g++ 4.4/4.8. Also openssl 1.0.2. But, after install it should be replaced with new ones, otherwise mysql will not work in asterisk, also Freeswitch.

Also old compiled version with old openssl and gcc allow to execute `curl`, otherwise it's should be replaced with `shell`.

Replacing new openssl with old one:

```
# will install libssl-dev as a dependency
apt install libmysqlclient-dev

# download required package manually 
apt download libssl1.0.0
apt download libssl1.0-dev
apt download libcurl3
apt download libcurl-openssl1.0-dev

# remove libssl-dev without removing libmysqlclient-dev
dpkg -r --force-depends libssl-dev
dpkg -r --force-depends libcurl4
dpkg -r --force-depends libcurl4-openssl-dev

# install libssl1.0-dev manually
dpkg -i libssl1.0-dev_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.4_amd64.deb
dpkg -i libcurl3_7.58.0-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
dpkg -i libcurl-openssl1.0-dev_7.58.0-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use older SSL version(which usually mean other OS too) OR newer asterisk version.

1.8.x is not supported anymore.

Comment: I used gcc/g++ 4.4 and openssl1.0.2. Not working anyway.

Comment: 1.0.1beta for sure works(version under centos 5). Check that your configure found correct version of openssl.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dahdi` as a module, and not recompile the whole Asterisk.

You just compile `dahdi`

I've done this few times with 1.8.32, and never recompiled the distro Asterisk.

Comment: I installed dahdi 2.11.2 complete before starting compile Asterisk for install, which is a general recomendation for general instalation. Also i select dahdi as module of Asterisk compile/instalation. 

Main moment it's that tcptls.o jusc cause me errors on compile.